# Проблема в совместном использовании curl и exe

Tags: c++, c, curl, консоль

Я написал программу,которая работает с текстовым файлом и должна отправить его по email.Для отправки по email использовал curl.Я вызываю curl из программы с помощью API функции `WinExec()`.Программа работает правильно,когда я запускаю её из IDE(Codeblocks),все вызывается,отправка по email идет,но вот когда я её просто запускаю не из ide,отправка email не происходит.Мне кажется,что проблема в том,что IDE вызывает консоль на несколько секунд и дает curl`у вывести туда все что надо,а когда я запускаю программу вручную,то консоль не вызывается(мне она мешает)
Вывод в консоль,когда я запускаю из IDE:
[image: Вывод curl]

Как мне сделать так,чтоб дать время выполниться curl и чтоб программа не вызывала консоль на долго или если уж вызывала,то чтоб она пропала быстрее,дав выполниться всем командам?
Примерный код программы:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
    char current_work_dir[700];
    char clonedir[250];
    char clonedir3[250];
    strcat(clonedir3,"\"");
    _getcwd(current_work_dir, sizeof(current_work_dir));
    _getcwd(clonedir, sizeof(clonedir));
    strcat(clonedir3,clonedir);
    strcat(clonedir3,"\\bin\\Debug\\mail.txt\" -k --anyauth");
    printf("%s",current_work_dir);
    strcat(current_work_dir,"\\curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -v --mail-from \"andybelous2@gmail.com\" --mail-rcpt \"andybelous2@gmail.com\" --ssl -u andybelous2@gmail.com:ПАСВОРД Я ПИШУ -T ");
    strcat(current_work_dir,clonedir3);
    WinExec(current_work_dir, SW_HIDE);
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У меня была похожая задача... Вобщем, я плюнул, взял библиотеку curl и просто встроил нужный мне код в программу...

Comment: Сишных библиотек для отправки почты - вагоны. Для Windows уж точно нет никакого смысла использовать внешние утилиты (тем более что это создаёт лишнюю и ненужную зависимость для программы).

Comment: @PinkTux Я ничего не знаю о сокетах,протоколах и тд,программа незамысловатая и мне было бы гораздо проще использовать curl

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ошибку.Дело в том,что функция _getcwd() при запуске из IDE выдавала неполный путь к файлу,поэтому мне приходилось вручную дописывать `\\bin\\Debug`.
При запуске вручную,функция возвращала полный путь,уже с `\\bin\\Debug`и команда не выполнялась.Для меня пока загадка,как так может быть,потому что IDE,по идее, запускает один и тот же файл,что и я.

Comment: О, где-то я этот ужасный код уже видел сегодня. Почитайте там мой комментарий. И ещё, возьмите что ли книгу какую-нибудь или доходчивое руководство по работе с библиотеками в Си.